# Selenium Browser crashes when not in front

Tags: python, selenium, applescript

I'm using Selenium (with Python) for automation. Selenium seems to crash whenever it clicks on a button while the window is not in focus. I want to be able to run this script even if the window is behind something else.

Would I be better off trying to figure out a way to make it work in the background, or would my best option be to write something bring the window to the front at that part of the script?

How can I bring the browser to the front?

EDIT: Just to add, this is on a Mac. Is there some way to use AppleScript in Python to focus the window?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: The problem with the stack trace is that it crashes after the actual problem. It's able to click the button, but nothing happens so then it crashes at the next step. It's almost as if the button turns into a label when the window isn't in focus.

Comment: You can use [`osascript`](http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2007/05/08/using-python-and-applescript-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-mac.html) to call AppleScript from Python.  My preferred approach is to run the scraper in a separate environment using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  That way it does what it needs without ever interfering with my work.  You might also want to look into headless approaches using PhantomJS.